# How to Use JAXB with Java 11 Without Using Maven

Tags: maven, jaxb, eclipse-rcp, rcp, java-11

As of Java 11 it is necessary to get JAXB from a separate library, not from the JDK.  There are plenty of tutorials on the Web showing how to do that, but they all use Maven.  The project I need to fix is an Eclipse RCP application. There does not seem to be an easy to make that work with Maven, as Maven essentially takes over most of what Eclipse would do but doesn't have RCP development capabilities.

Sooner or later Maven gets the required libraries. I would like to find another way to get and use whatever libraries are needed, just without using Maven. It should be possible. I just haven't found it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did what I wanted by downloading the needed JARs from https://mvnrepository.com/.